# Can I combine Spring @Profile and @Primary annotations to force bean choice when doing development?

Tags: java, spring

I work on a team that uses lots of libraries that we have little control over.

One of them introduces a bean that I want to replace when running locally, using the "dev" profile. It implements the `SuperClient` interface.

It appears I can do this using the following, but is there a better way to do this?
Remember the constraints are that I don't have control over the other bean that is typically injected, so I can't add `@Conditional` annotations to it.
And I can't qualify every place it's injected, as I don't control much of that code either.

```
@Component
@Primary
@Profile("dev")
public class MyLocalDevelopmentOnlyReplacment implements SuperClient {
...
}
```

Note that I'd like to commit this class to our repo. to simplify local development for the entire team.

Comment: The solution is valid and used in many projects. Especially for test environments. But also for local development or build servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggested seems to work fine for my use case, and is what we're using now in our code that we control. Note I added logging to the methods that are called as well that log something like the following, and watched the logs to see if this showed up, and it didn't (as I hoped)

**"DEV ONLY usage: If found in any non-prod or prod environment, please log as a bug"**

```
@Component
@Primary
@Profile("dev")
public class MyLocalDevelopmentOnlyReplacment implements SuperClient {
...
}
```